# how to run a python program on button click in Qt Creator and show result on Qlabel

Tags: python, pandas, qt, libraries

i have tried to run execute python program on button click but getting error ......

**Qt program**:

```
QProcess p;
QStringList params;
params<<"C:/Users/user/Desktop/image/temp.py";

p.start("C:/Users/user/anaconda3/python.exe",params);    
p.waitForFinished(-1);    
qDebug()<<"finished";

QStringp_stdout=p.readAll();    
qDebug()<<p_stdout;
QStringp_stderr=p.readAllStandardError();    
if(!p_stderr.isEmpty());
qDebug()<<"Pythonerror:"<<p_stderr;
```

Python program **temp.py**:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def change(path1,path2):
    im1=Image.open(path1,"r")
    im2=Image.open(path2,"r")

    buffer1=np.asarray(im1) 
    buffer2=np.asarray(im2)
    buffer3=buffer1-buffer2

    changed=Image.fromarray(buffer3)
    im1.show()
    im2.show()

    changed.show()
    changed.save(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\image\changed.jpg")

    return(changed.show)

change(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\image\Vale.jpg",r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\image\Vale2.jpg")
```

**ERROR on QT:**

```
finished
""
Python error:
 "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/image/temp.py", line 1, in <module>\r\n from PIL import Image\r\n File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 94, in <module>\r\n from . import _imaging as core\r\nImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.\r\n"
```

**Second approach in Qt:** *(python program is same as temp.py)*

```
QStringprogram("C:/Users/user/anaconda3/python.exe");

QStringListargs=QStringList()<<"C:/Users/user/Desktop/image/temp.py";

int exitcode=QProcess::execute(program,args);
```

**Error (Qt):**

```
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/image/temp.py", line 1, in <module> 

from PIL import Image
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 94, in <module>
from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: It looks like the linker error `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.` which is returned in both cases is the problem.

Comment: if any another approach is there,please tell.

Comment: Try this: Add DLL location (Example: C:\Programs\Python\Python35\DLLs on windows) in the Environment variables path.

Comment: do u mean by to add path of python ? actually i m using spyder(anaconda IDE).should i add location of python of anaconda ?